# How do I automate the deletion of a worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I'm using `Application.Sheets("Sheet6").Delete` to delete a sheet, and it causes a popup that asks if I'm sure. How do I automatically select delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your code to disable the display of alerts before you delete your sheet; Then enable the alerts after the delete code executes

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet6").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the alerts before you do the delete. Then turn them back on like this:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Sheets("Sheet6").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your display alerts off for Excel

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Sheets("Sheet6").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```